# Append to a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a dataframe, and each time I run experiments I would like to add a new entry.

I have N tests; some may run while some may not; which is why I decided to use Pandas, so I can use timestamp as unique record identifier, and each test is saved in its own row.

```
dataset = [{"datetime":"0102172230" ,"test1":0.3, "test2":0.4},{"datetime":"0102172232" ,"test1":0.33, "test2":0.32, "test3":0.54},{"datetime":"0102172235" ,"test2":0.28, "test3":0.51}]
```

This is how my data may look like; and this is the output when I print the dataframe, using the datetime as index:

```
            test1  test2  test3
datetime                       
0102172230   0.30   0.40    NaN
0102172232   0.33   0.32   0.54
0102172235    NaN   0.28   0.51
```

Now, I am saving this as dataframe in a pickle, which is fine, although now I would like to add more data to the dataframe, every time I run a new set of experiments, so the new set is add at the bottom as new row.

I did check the docs and I can re-load the dataframe from the pickle, but I can't find a straight way to add a new "row" (I am aware that Pandas is not a traditional DB, so it does not have "records" per se).

How do you append data to the dataframe, so I can add for example another row below the existing ones? The only way that I found so far is to output the dataframe to a list of dictionaries, append another dictionary to the list with the new set of experiments, and re-create again the dataframe, but this seems quite involuted and inconvenient to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(dataset).set_index('datetime')])
```

Comment: Trying now; although I am not clear about the syntax. pd is pandas, df is just a new dataframe name? Or df is my first dataframe?

Comment: df is the name of your dataframe with you old measurements, then you are going to concatenate the a dataframe built buy dataset to the bottom of your old dataframe and reassign that back to df.